# Increasing Resolution of Image By Splitting Image Pixel into Smaller Pixels | Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, digital-image-processing

I have two MODIS satellite images with same custom band, one of `1000m/px` resolution and other of `250m/px`. I want to compute their mean 'image' and display as map layer.

My current way of achieving this is as follows:

```
var img_col = ee.ImageCollection(img_1.select('DP1'), img_2.select('DP1));
img_col = img_col.mean();
Map.addLayer(img_col, params_obj);
```

But this does not result in raster image with `250m/px` resolution. How to specifically generate image with resolution equal to the highest of two initial images?

Comment: Earth Engine generally resamples images as needed for the *output;* adding explicit resampling is usually not necessary. Could you [edit] your question to describe how you want to *use* the resampled image — what final result you want? That will help us answer your question with the best approach.

Comment: @kevin-reid Thank you for replying. I see... I want to take the mean of two images. One is 1000m/px resolution and other is of 65m/px. So like you said by simply computing their mean in GEE will automatically do resampling and resulting mean image will be of 65m/px resolution?

Comment: _Both_ images will be automatically resampled to whatever the _output_ resolution is — for example if you use `Map.addLayer` to get an interactive map, it is whatever resolution the map is zoomed to. That's why I asked you to update your question to specify what you want to do with the result. The final operation (layer, export, `reduceRegion`, etc.) determines the resolution, and if you say what you're doing with the image we can say how to control the resolution.

Comment: Here's what I'm doing. I have two images each containing one same custom band. But one image has 1000m and other 65m per pixel resolution. I create custom image collection from these two images and then compute mean using `ee.Reducer.mean()`.

Comment: There is no problem with doing that — as I already said, it will be resampled to the output resolution (not the resolution of either image). In order to get a definitive answer, **please [edit] your question — don't just write a comment — to specify what you are _finally_ doing with the images**. Are you displaying a map, or exporting, or what? Ideally, provide a runnable code sample showing the entire calculation you're planning on, if it's reasonably simple. Then we will be able to answer with exactly what Earth Engine will do, and whether you need to worry about resampling (probably not).

Comment: @kevin-reid, I've edited the question.

Comment: OK, I see that you're using `Map.addLayer`. That means that the output _should_ be at the full resolution as long as you've zoomed in on the map far enough (and if you zoom farther in, you will see pixelation, possibly at a slant depending on what the projection of your images is). If that's not what you're seeing, we need enough information to reproduce the problem: provide a complete script that we can actually run (using public MODIS images) that shows us the missing resolution you're seeing.